# PHP OOP Database Class - Is it really needed?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm currently learning to code using OOP in PHP and have quite often come across database classes and abstraction layers. I'm coding a CMS as a big challenge and I started to code a database class without thinking about it too much.

I'm actually leaning towards using MySQLi as is (I think it's pretty good to use as is), rather than creating a class to deal with CRUD operations so do I really need a class to deal with all that stuff?

If not, what would be the best way of going about connecting to a database, just do it at the start of my application and pass the connection around? Or is there really a huge benefit of coding a database class that I'm missing?

I'm thinking that error handling would be one such benefit but if I'm keeping my class as close to MySQLi as possible, is that a good enough reason to go ahead with a class?

Comment: Why close a good question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the good question.

> PHP OOP Database Class - Is it really needed?

Definitely yes, but only if you don't like screenfuls of repetitive code for the every query executed in your code.

If you take a fresh look at the code you need to perform one average query, you may notice that it's amount just horrible. While all you need is to just define a query, pass variables, run it and get results, you have to write thousands of useless operators, repeated for the every query.

An example right from the manual (even without error handling)

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($district);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $district;
}
```

An example of using a database helper class:

```
$district = $db->getOne("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?s", $city);
echo $district;
```

and that's for the single row only. For the array of rows the amount of code will be doubled in case of using raw API

In case of using mysqli things gets even worse.

Let's take simple example. Imagine there is a array of ids of unknown size. You need to add them all tho IN statement in the simple query

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (1,2,3) // filled from array.
```

Try to get your data using mysqli prepared statements

Answer (score 7):

The main benefit is that if you can get all your code to go through your database objects. You can easily change the database implementation in the future. You say you are learning towards mysqli but say half way down the line you changed to PDO, you would have to refactor -everything-.

Using your custom database objects, you can simply alter the integration without effecting the rest of the code. E.g. Your objects->connect() function could still be called exactly as it is right now but the underlying code would change and as it was all within your custom class, the changes you make are minimal.

This is just one of many benefits. A custom class that interfaces with the database object to run queries and store results are quite common to see (the model part of an MVC - usually extending a common base object often called a RecordSet or similar that has functions to run select/update/delete/etc). As again, you can easily change the implementation from one method to another.

What I've described is a pretty common advantage for Object Orientated Programming in general. Please see Your Common Sense's answer for another good advantage.

Comment: In addition to these very good points, you also give the customers of your CMS (assuming you will redistribute it) a choice of databases. If you use an ORM object, switching to Oracle or pgsql can be very easy, you just switch the connectivity.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Off the top of my head, Drupal supports pgsql as well as MySQL. I think Typo3 supports MySQL, MariaDB and Oracle. To clarify, I didn't mean 'switching' as in migrating, I meant you could have customers using Oracle, customers using MySQL etc. with the same core PHP code base.

Comment: @YourCommonSense MariaDB has a compatibility mode with MySQL but they are [not the same any more](http://blog.mariadb.org/explanation-on-mariadb-10-0/). MySQL has features which MariaDB has not yet implemented, and vice versa.